# Azure Resource Manager API Permissions for Subscription Co-Admin

Tags: c#, azure, permissions, active-directory, azure-resource-manager

I am trying to create a asp.net core based solution using the Azure Resource Manager API libraries to manage resources on a single subscription.

When I try to authenticate using an subscription co-administrator account I receive permissions errors. Below is the steps I have tried.

**Created a project based on following examples:**
https://github.com/pratapbhaskar/azure-resource-manager-active-directory
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-api-authentication

**In management portal:**

1. Created active directory app entry.
2. Set AD app entry Multi-tenanted to True.
3. Give AD app entry Azure Active Directory read profile permissions.

**Tried logging in to application using subscription co-admin account and received the following error:**

> AADSTS65005: The client application has requested access to resource
>   'https://management.core.windows.net/'. This request has failed
>   because the client has not specified this resource in its
>   requiredResourceAccess list.

**Attempted fix:**

1. Open AD app and add permissions for: "Windows Azure Service Management API"
2. Add delegated permissions "Access Azure Service Management as organization users (preview)"

**Tried logging in to application using subscription co-admin account and received the following error:**

> AADSTS90093: This application requires application permissions to another application. Consent for application permissions can only be
>   performed by an administrator. Sign out and sign in as an
>   administrator or contact one of your organization's administrators.

Comment: Have you fixed this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error message, the app you have config which require the admin to give the consent and the login-in account is not the Global admin in its tenant.

Please ensure that the app doesn't grant the other's application which need the admin to give the consent.

I download the code sample and config the app with the figure below, and I am able to login the app successfully:

[image]